# Run actions with delay between them

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronization

I've got a list of actions that I want executed one after another.
Let's say we've got a boxing-bag workout:

A beep sounds, then after 2 seconds the instructor tells to the athlete what to do ('FOOTWORK'). After 15 seconds the instructor tells the athlete to change what he is doing ('TECHNIQUE')... This goes on till a minute has passed. Then, the instructor repeats this procedure 3 times.

I am trying to build some library that does exactly that but I'm having issues with the delays between each action. Here is what I have done so far:

```
class Action{
    constructor(name = "Action", actualAction){
        this.name = name;
        this.actualAction = actualAction;
    }

    run(){
        console.log("Executing Action: " + this.name);
        this.actualAction();
    }
}

function repeat(times){
    var timesLeft = times;
    return function(){
        timesLeft--;
        return timesLeft > 0;
    }
}

class SleepAction extends Action{
    constructor(ms, nextAction){
        super("Sleep " + ms);
        this.ms = ms;
        this.nextAction = nextAction;
    }

    run(){
        setTimeout(this.nextAction.run(), this.ms);
    }
}

class Block extends Action{
    constructor(name = "Block", actions, repeat){
        super(name);
        this.repeat = repeat;
        this.instructions = actions;
    }

    run(){
        this.instructions.forEach(function(action) {
            action.run();
        });

        if(this.repeat()){
            this.run();
        }
    }
}
```

You can tell that I am using **setTimeout** to try to get this to work, but all the actions run simultaneously in this example:

```
var doNothing = new Action("Nothing", function(){});

var boxingBagPreset = new Block("Boxing Bag 15-15-15-15 3 Times", 
        [beepAction, 
        new SleepAction(2000, new Block("Tiny Pause", [
            new Action("FOOTWORK", textToSpeech("FOOTWORK")),
            new SleepAction(15000, new Block("Sleep 15", [
                new Action("SPEED", textToSpeech("SPEED")),
                new SleepAction(15000, new Block("Sleep 15", [
                    new Action("POWER", textToSpeech("POWER")),
                    new SleepAction(15000, new Block("Sleep 15", [
                        new Action("REST", textToSpeech("REST")),
                        new SleepAction(15000, new Block("Sleep 15", [doNothing], repeat(1)))
                    ], repeat(1)))
                ], repeat(1)))
            ] , repeat(1)))
        ], repeat(1)))],
    repeat(3));
```

What do I need to change in order for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are immediately invoking the function and passing the result instead of passing the function itself to `setTimeout`.

Try this:

```js
class SleepAction extends Action{
    constructor(ms, nextAction){
        super("Sleep " + ms);
        this.ms = ms;
        this.nextAction = nextAction;
    }

    run(){
        var func = () => this.nextAction.run();
        setTimeout(func, this.ms);
    }
}
```

Due to the way `this` is handled, you can't just pass `this.nextAction.run` because the `this` will be different when `setTimeout` calls it.

In this example, I created a new function to capture `this`.

Comment: Alright, thank you it solves the issue, except the repeat() part. Do you have any recommendation except expanding the chain 3 times in order to make it work? (It goes like BEEP-BEEP-BEEP *15s sleep* TECH-TECH-TECH ... etc

Comment: @Zarkopafilis I don't understand but maybe you can create a new question and elaborate.